# How to pass arguments with 'new Responder'? actionscript 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I have the following code in action script 3:

```
async.addResponder(new Responder(result, defaultFaultHandler));
```

result is a function that receives data from remoteobjet async, calling this function normally, but must go along with other arguments result, example:

```
async.addResponder(new Responder(result(args...), defaultFaultHandler));
```

How should I proceed in this way? I tried many things, but see no solution yet.

Thanks to everyone now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
async.addRespondor(new AsyncResponder(resultHandler, faultHandler, token));
```

where resultHandler and faultHandler are function references and token can be an arbitrary object you want access to later. Then in your resultHandler, you get the token like this:

```
function resultHanlder(result:ResultEvent, token:Object):void
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure like this.

```
async.addResponder(
          new Responder(function(event) { result(event, args); }, 
                        defaultFaultHandler)
          );
```